# Designing a factory reset switch

Tags: digital-logic, pcb-design, reset

I want to add a factory reset onto a PCB design I am working on. Basically, I want it to be a switch (or combination of) that will never be "accidentally" closed and therefore accidentally factory reset the uC.

My initial thought was to add a switch you can only press with a needle that you see often in consumer products, except this PCB will not be inside an enclosure and I believe the "needle" requirement comes from designing the enclosure to have a small opening that only a needle can penetrate.

My next idea is to use an 8PDT switch (or similar) where only 1 combination of the 8 switches (1 / 2*8 = 1/256 = 0.4%) will output a "1" to the factory reset.

Anyone have any experience with this, or suggestions for alternate methods?

Thanks.

Comment: Make it like that game Simon Says!

Comment: By "8PDT" do you mean an 8-position DIP switch? Because an [8PDT switch](http://www.mouser.com/Electromechanical/Switches/_/N-5g2h?Keyword=8PDT&FS=True) is just a two-state device.

Comment: Yeah, meant a DIP switch where each could be switched independently. Good catch.

Answer (score 5):

Use a standard PCB button, but require the user to press it in a sequence that would not happen accidentally.

For example: 1 long press, followed by a long release, followed by a short press. The long press and release could be 2 seconds each, the short press could be 0.5s. Obviously you have to allow for a tolerance on these timings.

Or, press the button 3 times within a certain time interval, etc.

Comment: I like it a lot, but we'd like to keep the majority of the processing in hardware and I think setting up this timing circuitry may be tough. If we decide to include software algorithms to determine the "intention" of the button press, this seems like a very elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

Ideas:

- Use a standard PCB button and check for status immediately after power-up reset. If button is pressed then perform the factory reset. Note that if the button is jammed for any reason that a factory reset will occur.
- Use a 20 s hold-in. Netgear use this approach on many of their SOHO routers. With this approach you can check that the button is open on power-up and subsequently closed for 20 s. The long time delay is unlikely to be reached by someone just probing about.

Comment: Thanks! I like the 2nd idea a lot, especially since it seems pretty simple to implement in hardware.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen people use a relatively inaccessible push-button (paper clip or must open case to access) that is held down during power-up.

That ensures enough intention that it won't get accidentally triggered, IMO.

Comment: You can also use DIP switch with cover to prevent accidental activation. Something like this: http://www.grayhill.com/assets/1/7/DIP_Accessories.pdf